# Sum of numbers, where some cells contain a range of values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working on an Excel spreadsheet to calculate costs of different travel options, by summing different expenses for the trip. However, some of the costs are not known exactly. I only know ballpark ranges. Other expenses I do know the exact costs of. Which ones are ranges and which ones are exact numbers will vary depending on the travel option. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
        Option 1    Option 2    Option 3

Expense 1   $75-$125    $185        $65
Expense 2   $175        $325        $125-$150
Expense 3   $0      $25-$120    $25-$77
Expense 4   $22-$35 $12     $66

Total       $272-$335   $547-$642   $281-$358
```

I want to have Excel automatically calculate the totals. I'd like to avoid having separate cells for the upper and lower bounds, to keep things cleaner, and to avoid having to enter the same value twice if it is a fixed amount.

Is there any way to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this Array formula:

```
="$" & SUM(B2:B5)+SUM(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(B2:B5)),--LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B5,"$",""),FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(B2:B5,"$",""))-1))) & "-$" & SUM(B2:B5)+SUM(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(B2:B5)),--MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B5,"$",""),FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(B2:B5,"$",""))+1,999)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]